# Calculate a trailing average using day of year closest to anchor date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, algorithm

I have a dataframe of weekly values for different series identifiers as follows.  The week entries are made for each series every week but don't coincide year after year (eg, 1/1 one year, 1/3 the next, 1/2, etc.):

```
period  series  value

    2017-05-12  R33 720
    2017-05-12  R33 1057
    2017-05-12  R33 337
    2017-05-12  R34 161
    2017-05-12  R35 244
    2017-05-12  R48 2369
    2017-05-19  R31 390
    2017-05-19  R32 562
    2017-05-19  R33 1076
    2017-05-19  R33 738
    2017-05-19  R33 338
    2017-05-19  R34 166
    2017-05-19  R35 250
    2017-05-19  R48 2444
    2017-05-26  R31 419
    2017-05-26  R32 585
    2017-05-26  R33 342
    2017-05-26  R33 755
    2017-05-26  R33 1097
    2017-05-26  R34 166
    2017-05-26  R35 258
    2017-05-26  R48 2525
    2017-06-02  R31 457
    2017-06-02  R32 614
    2017-06-02  R33 774
    2017-06-02  R33 345
    2017-06-02  R33 1119
    2017-06-02  R34 172
    2017-06-02  R35 269
    2017-06-02  R48 2631
    2017-06-09  R31 491
    2017-06-09  R32 634
    2017-06-09  R33 1133
    2017-06-09  R33 784
    2017-06-09  R33 348
    2017-06-09  R34 177
    2017-06-09  R35 274
    2017-06-09  R48 2709
    2017-06-16  R31 513
    2017-06-16  R32 656
    2017-06-16  R33 1138
    2017-06-16  R33 343
    2017-06-16  R33 794
    2017-06-16  R34 182
    2017-06-16  R35 281
    2017-06-16  R48 2770
    2017-06-23  R31 536
    2017-06-23  R32 676
    2017-06-23  R33 341
    2017-06-23  R33 799
    2017-06-23  R33 1140
    2017-06-23  R34 184
    2017-06-23  R35 280
    2017-06-23  R48 2816
    2017-06-30  R31 564
    2017-06-30  R32 699
    2017-06-30  R33 1141
    2017-06-30  R33 810
    2017-06-30  R33 332
    2017-06-30  R34 187
    2017-06-30  R35 287
    2017-06-30  R48 2878
    2017-07-07  R31 588
    2017-07-07  R32 719
    2017-07-07  R33 1144
    2017-07-07  R33 817
    2017-07-07  R33 327
    2017-07-07  R34 193
    2017-07-07  R35 292
    2017-07-07  R48 2936
    2017-07-14  R31 609
    2017-07-14  R32 733
    2017-07-14  R33 319
    2017-07-14  R33 816
    2017-07-14  R33 1135
    2017-07-14  R34 194
    2017-07-14  R35 292
    2017-07-14  R48 2963
    2017-07-21  R31 626
    2017-07-21  R32 743
    2017-07-21  R33 308
    2017-07-21  R33 812
    2017-07-21  R33 1120
    2017-07-21  R34 197
    2017-07-21  R35 294
    2017-07-21  R48 2980
    2017-07-28  R31 651
    2017-07-28  R32 754
    2017-07-28  R33 805
    2017-07-28  R33 296
    2017-07-28  R33 1101
    2017-07-28  R34 200
    2017-07-28  R35 293
    2017-07-28  R48 2999
    2017-08-04  R31 673
    2017-08-04  R32 771
    2017-08-04  R33 1094
    2017-08-04  R33 804
    2017-08-04  R33 290
    2017-08-04  R34 202
    2017-08-04  R35 289
    2017-08-04  R48 3029
    2017-08-11  R31 701
    2017-08-11  R32 798
    2017-08-11  R33 804
    2017-08-11  R33 1087
    2017-08-11  R33 283
    2017-08-11  R34 204
    2017-08-11  R35 292
    2017-08-11  R48 3082
    2017-08-18  R31 728
    2017-08-18  R32 821
    2017-08-18  R33 274
    2017-08-18  R33 800
    2017-08-18  R33 1074
    2017-08-18  R34 206
    2017-08-18  R35 296
    2017-08-18  R48 3125
    2017-08-25  R31 749
    2017-08-25  R32 840
    2017-08-25  R33 1060
    2017-08-25  R33 262
    2017-08-25  R33 797
    2017-08-25  R34 205
    2017-08-25  R35 301
    2017-08-25  R48 3155
    2017-09-01  R31 781
    2017-09-01  R32 872
    2017-09-01  R33 266
    2017-09-01  R33 800
    2017-09-01  R33 1066
    2017-09-01  R34 205
    2017-09-01  R35 296
    2017-09-01  R48 3220
    2017-09-08  R31 809
    2017-09-08  R32 906
    2017-09-08  R33 285
    2017-09-08  R33 1092
    2017-09-08  R33 807
    2017-09-08  R34 208
    2017-09-08  R35 296
    2017-09-08  R48 3311
    2017-09-15  R31 833
    2017-09-15  R32 938
    2017-09-15  R33 304
    2017-09-15  R33 821
    2017-09-15  R33 1125
    2017-09-15  R34 212
    2017-09-15  R35 300
    2017-09-15  R48 3408
    2017-09-22  R31 848
    2017-09-22  R32 964
    2017-09-22  R33 305
    2017-09-22  R33 1130
    2017-09-22  R33 825
    2017-09-22  R34 217
    2017-09-22  R35 307
    2017-09-22  R48 3466
    2017-09-29  R31 861
    2017-09-29  R32 989
    2017-09-29  R33 1127
    2017-09-29  R33 300
    2017-09-29  R33 827
    2017-09-29  R34 220
    2017-09-29  R35 311
    2017-09-29  R48 3508
    2017-10-06  R31 884
    2017-10-06  R32 1024
    2017-10-06  R33 838
    2017-10-06  R33 1149
    2017-10-06  R33 310
    2017-10-06  R34 223
    2017-10-06  R35 315
    2017-10-06  R48 3595
    2017-10-13  R31 901
    2017-10-13  R32 1054
    2017-10-13  R33 302
    2017-10-13  R33 1150
    2017-10-13  R33 848
    2017-10-13  R34 224
    2017-10-13  R35 316
    2017-10-13  R48 3645
    2017-10-20  R31 915
    2017-10-20  R32 1082
    2017-10-20  R33 1174
    2017-10-20  R33 861
    2017-10-20  R33 313
    2017-10-20  R34 224
    2017-10-20  R35 315
    2017-10-20  R48 3710
    2017-10-27  R31 926
    2017-10-27  R32 1107
    2017-10-27  R33 324
    2017-10-27  R33 1199
    2017-10-27  R33 874
    2017-10-27  R34 226
    2017-10-27  R35 317
    2017-10-27  R48 3775
    2017-11-03  R31 925
    2017-11-03  R32 1112
    2017-11-03  R33 876
    2017-11-03  R33 336
    2017-11-03  R33 1212
    2017-11-03  R34 224
    2017-11-03  R35 317
    2017-11-03  R48 3790
    2017-11-10  R31 915
    2017-11-10  R32 1108
    2017-11-10  R33 1214
    2017-11-10  R33 341
    2017-11-10  R33 873
    2017-11-10  R34 220
    2017-11-10  R35 315
    2017-11-10  R48 3772
    2017-11-17  R31 891
    2017-11-17  R32 1090
    2017-11-17  R33 1211
    2017-11-17  R33 871
    2017-11-17  R33 340
    2017-11-17  R34 220
    2017-11-17  R35 314
    2017-11-17  R48 3726
    2017-11-24  R31 876
    2017-11-24  R32 1068
    2017-11-24  R33 866
    2017-11-24  R33 348
    2017-11-24  R33 1214
    2017-11-24  R34 221
    2017-11-24  R35 314
    2017-11-24  R48 3693
    2017-12-01  R31 868
    2017-12-01  R32 1058
    2017-12-01  R33 875
    2017-12-01  R33 360
    2017-12-01  R33 1235
    2017-12-01  R34 221
    2017-12-01  R35 313
    2017-12-01  R48 3695
    2017-12-08  R31 855
    2017-12-08  R32 1033
    2017-12-08  R33 1220
    2017-12-08  R33 360
    2017-12-08  R33 860
    2017-12-08  R34 213
    2017-12-08  R35 305
    2017-12-08  R48 3626
    2017-12-15  R31 811
    2017-12-15  R32 980
    2017-12-15  R33 825
    2017-12-15  R33 330
    2017-12-15  R33 1155
    2017-12-15  R34 204
    2017-12-15  R35 294
    2017-12-15  R48 3444
    2017-12-22  R31 782
    2017-12-22  R32 941
    2017-12-22  R33 809
    2017-12-22  R33 1133
    2017-12-22  R33 324
    2017-12-22  R34 195
    2017-12-22  R35 281
    2017-12-22  R48 3332
    2017-12-29  R31 740
    2017-12-29  R32 875
    2017-12-29  R33 1060
    2017-12-29  R33 759
    2017-12-29  R33 302
    2017-12-29  R34 183
    2017-12-29  R35 268
    2017-12-29  R48 3126
    2018-01-05  R31 664
    2018-01-05  R32 778
    2018-01-05  R33 683
    2018-01-05  R33 224
    2018-01-05  R33 907
    2018-01-05  R34 167
    2018-01-05  R35 251
    2018-01-05  R48 2767
    2018-01-12  R31 614
    2018-01-12  R32 717
    2018-01-12  R33 206
    2018-01-12  R33 851
    2018-01-12  R33 646
    2018-01-12  R34 158
    2018-01-12  R35 244
    2018-01-12  R48 2584
    2018-01-19  R31 555
    2018-01-19  R32 634
    2018-01-19  R33 578
    2018-01-19  R33 729
    2018-01-19  R33 151
    2018-01-19  R34 145
    2018-01-19  R35 233
    2018-01-19  R48 2296
    2018-01-26  R31 525
    2018-01-26  R32 596
    2018-01-26  R33 169
    2018-01-26  R33 550
    2018-01-26  R33 719
    2018-01-26  R34 137
    2018-01-26  R35 220
    2018-01-26  R48 2197
    2018-02-02  R31 488
    2018-02-02  R32 543
    2018-02-02  R33 518
    2018-02-02  R33 703
    2018-02-02  R33 184
    2018-02-02  R34 131
    2018-02-02  R35 213
    2018-02-02  R48 2078
    2018-02-09  R31 432
    2018-02-09  R32 468
    2018-02-09  R33 472
    2018-02-09  R33 178
    2018-02-09  R33 649
    2018-02-09  R34 122
    2018-02-09  R35 213
    2018-02-09  R48 1884
    2018-02-16  R31 403
    2018-02-16  R32 428
    2018-02-16  R33 614
    2018-02-16  R33 440
    2018-02-16  R33 175
    2018-02-16  R34 111
    2018-02-16  R35 204
    2018-02-16  R48 1760
    2018-02-23  R31 382
    2018-02-23  R32 398
    2018-02-23  R33 429
    2018-02-23  R33 611
    2018-02-23  R33 183
    2018-02-23  R34 102
    2018-02-23  R35 189
    2018-02-23  R48 1682
    2018-03-02  R31 359
    2018-03-02  R32 380
    2018-03-02  R33 612
    2018-03-02  R33 189
    2018-03-02  R33 423
    2018-03-02  R34 97
    2018-03-02  R35 177
    2018-03-02  R48 1625
    2018-03-09  R31 314
    2018-03-09  R32 350
    2018-03-09  R33 186
    2018-03-09  R33 420
    2018-03-09  R33 606
    2018-03-09  R34 93
    2018-03-09  R35 169
    2018-03-09  R48 1532
    2018-03-16  R31 270
    2018-03-16  R32 315
    2018-03-16  R33 182
    2018-03-16  R33 602
    2018-03-16  R33 419
    2018-03-16  R34 90
    2018-03-16  R35 169
    2018-03-16  R48 1446
    2018-03-23  R31 242
    2018-03-23  R32 284
    2018-03-23  R33 181
    2018-03-23  R33 422
    2018-03-23  R33 603
    2018-03-23  R34 88
    2018-03-23  R35 166
    2018-03-23  R48 1383
    2018-03-30  R31 229
    2018-03-30  R32 266
    2018-03-30  R33 188
    2018-03-30  R33 606
    2018-03-30  R33 419
    2018-03-30  R34 87
    2018-03-30  R35 166
    2018-03-30  R48 1354
    2018-04-06  R31 217
    2018-04-06  R32 246
    2018-04-06  R33 618
    2018-04-06  R33 196
    2018-04-06  R33 422
    2018-04-06  R34 83
    2018-04-06  R35 171
    2018-04-06  R48 1335
    2018-04-13  R31 207
    2018-04-13  R32 228
    2018-04-13  R33 606
    2018-04-13  R33 185
    2018-04-13  R33 421
    2018-04-13  R34 83
    2018-04-13  R35 175
    2018-04-13  R48 1299
    2018-04-20  R31 205
    2018-04-20  R32 211
    2018-04-20  R33 182
    2018-04-20  R33 421
    2018-04-20  R33 604
    2018-04-20  R34 84
    2018-04-20  R35 177
    2018-04-20  R48 1281
    2018-04-27  R31 223
    2018-04-27  R32 221
    2018-04-27  R33 626
    2018-04-27  R33 436
    2018-04-27  R33 190
    2018-04-27  R34 86
    2018-04-27  R35 187
    2018-04-27  R48 1343
    2018-05-04  R31 243
    2018-05-04  R32 240
    2018-05-04  R33 458
    2018-05-04  R33 204
    2018-05-04  R33 662
    2018-05-04  R34 92
    2018-05-04  R35 195
    2018-05-04  R48 1432
    2018-05-11  R31 275
    2018-05-11  R32 267
    2018-05-11  R33 477
    2018-05-11  R33 694
    2018-05-11  R33 216
    2018-05-11  R34 98
    2018-05-11  R35 204
    2018-05-11  R48 1538
    2018-05-18  R31 299
    2018-05-18  R32 288
    2018-05-18  R33 226
    2018-05-18  R33 496
    2018-05-18  R33 722
    2018-05-18  R34 107
    2018-05-18  R35 213
    2018-05-18  R48 1629
    2018-05-25  R31 328
    2018-05-25  R32 315
    2018-05-25  R33 235
    2018-05-25  R33 748
    2018-05-25  R33 514
    2018-05-25  R34 113
    2018-05-25  R35 221
    2018-05-25  R48 1725
    2018-06-01  R31 351
    2018-06-01  R32 341
    2018-06-01  R33 245
    2018-06-01  R33 773
    2018-06-01  R33 528
    2018-06-01  R34 121
    2018-06-01  R35 231
    2018-06-01  R48 1817
    2018-06-08  R31 377
    2018-06-08  R32 372
    2018-06-08  R33 252
    2018-06-08  R33 547
    2018-06-08  R33 800
    2018-06-08  R34 125
    2018-06-08  R35 239
    2018-06-08  R48 1913
    2018-06-15  R31 406
    2018-06-15  R32 401
    2018-06-15  R33 570
    2018-06-15  R33 828
    2018-06-15  R33 258
    2018-06-15  R34 127
    2018-06-15  R35 246
    2018-06-15  R48 2008
    2018-06-22  R31 430
    2018-06-22  R32 425
    2018-06-22  R33 252
    2018-06-22  R33 835
    2018-06-22  R33 583
    2018-06-22  R34 133
    2018-06-22  R35 251
    2018-06-22  R48 2074
    2018-06-29  R31 460
    2018-06-29  R32 455
    2018-06-29  R33 841
    2018-06-29  R33 245
    2018-06-29  R33 596
    2018-06-29  R34 139
    2018-06-29  R35 257
    2018-06-29  R48 2152
    2018-07-06  R31 480
    2018-07-06  R32 477
    2018-07-06  R33 843
    2018-07-06  R33 238
    2018-07-06  R33 605
    2018-07-06  R34 143
    2018-07-06  R35 260
    2018-07-06  R48 2203
    2018-07-13  R31 507
    2018-07-13  R32 501
    2018-07-13  R33 231
    2018-07-13  R33 838
    2018-07-13  R33 607
    2018-07-13  R34 144
    2018-07-13  R35 259
    2018-07-13  R48 2248
    2018-07-20  R31 527
    2018-07-20  R32 525
    2018-07-20  R33 820
    2018-07-20  R33 215
    2018-07-20  R33 605
    2018-07-20  R34 145
    2018-07-20  R35 256
    2018-07-20  R48 2272
    2018-07-27  R31 552
    2018-07-27  R32 552
    2018-07-27  R33 807
    2018-07-27  R33 206
    2018-07-27  R33 601
    2018-07-27  R34 146
    2018-07-27  R35 249
    2018-07-27  R48 2305
    2018-08-03  R31 574
    2018-08-03  R32 580
    2018-08-03  R33 808
    2018-08-03  R33 204
    2018-08-03  R33 604
    2018-08-03  R34 148
    2018-08-03  R35 244
    2018-08-03  R48 2353
    2018-08-10  R31 590
    2018-08-10  R32 604
    2018-08-10  R33 606
    2018-08-10  R33 195
    2018-08-10  R33 802
    2018-08-10  R34 151
    2018-08-10  R35 239
    2018-08-10  R48 2386
    2018-08-17  R31 611
    2018-08-17  R32 633
    2018-08-17  R33 609
    2018-08-17  R33 190
    2018-08-17  R33 799
    2018-08-17  R34 153
    2018-08-17  R35 238
    2018-08-17  R48 2435
    2018-08-24  R31 637
    2018-08-24  R32 669
    2018-08-24  R33 801
    2018-08-24  R33 188
    2018-08-24  R33 613
    2018-08-24  R34 157
    2018-08-24  R35 240
    2018-08-24  R48 2504
    2018-08-31  R31 659
    2018-08-31  R32 702
    2018-08-31  R33 183
    2018-08-31  R33 799
    2018-08-31  R33 615
    2018-08-31  R34 162
    2018-08-31  R35 246
    2018-08-31  R48 2567
    2018-09-07  R31 679
    2018-09-07  R32 734
    2018-09-07  R33 624
    2018-09-07  R33 182
    2018-09-07  R33 806
    2018-09-07  R34 166
    2018-09-07  R35 250
    2018-09-07  R48 2636
    2018-09-14  R31 709
    2018-09-14  R32 770
    2018-09-14  R33 184
    2018-09-14  R33 635
    2018-09-14  R33 818
    2018-09-14  R34 170
    2018-09-14  R35 255
    2018-09-14  R48 2722
    2018-09-21  R31 729
    2018-09-21  R32 800
    2018-09-21  R33 634
    2018-09-21  R33 173
    2018-09-21  R33 807
    2018-09-21  R34 173
    2018-09-21  R35 259
    2018-09-21  R48 2768
    2018-09-28  R31 763
    2018-09-28  R32 836
    2018-09-28  R33 829
    2018-09-28  R33 648
    2018-09-28  R33 181
    2018-09-28  R34 177
    2018-09-28  R35 262
    2018-09-28  R48 2866
    2018-10-05  R31 790
    2018-10-05  R32 871
    2018-10-05  R33 191
    2018-10-05  R33 854
    2018-10-05  R33 663
    2018-10-05  R34 180
    2018-10-05  R35 262
    2018-10-05  R48 2956
    2018-10-12  R31 812
    2018-10-12  R32 908
    2018-10-12  R33 877
    2018-10-12  R33 203
    2018-10-12  R33 673
    2018-10-12  R34 177
    2018-10-12  R35 264
    2018-10-12  R48 3037
    2018-10-19  R31 825
    2018-10-19  R32 934
    2018-10-19  R33 218
    2018-10-19  R33 896
    2018-10-19  R33 678
    2018-10-19  R34 177
    2018-10-19  R35 262
    2018-10-19  R48 3095
    2018-10-26  R31 826
    2018-10-26  R32 956
    2018-10-26  R33 919
    2018-10-26  R33 234
    2018-10-26  R33 686
    2018-10-26  R34 180
    2018-10-26  R35 262
    2018-10-26  R48 3143
    2018-11-02  R31 831
    2018-11-02  R32 980
    2018-11-02  R33 253
    2018-11-02  R33 949
    2018-11-02  R33 696
    2018-11-02  R34 182
    2018-11-02  R35 265
    2018-11-02  R48 3208
    2018-11-09  R31 835
    2018-11-09  R32 991
    2018-11-09  R33 272
    2018-11-09  R33 974
    2018-11-09  R33 702
    2018-11-09  R34 181
    2018-11-09  R35 266
    2018-11-09  R48 3247
    2018-11-16  R31 803
    2018-11-16  R32 959
    2018-11-16  R33 251
    2018-11-16  R33 668
    2018-11-16  R33 919
    2018-11-16  R34 174
    2018-11-16  R35 258
    2018-11-16  R48 3113
    2018-11-23  R31 778
    2018-11-23  R32 938
    2018-11-23  R33 654
    2018-11-23  R33 914
    2018-11-23  R33 259
    2018-11-23  R34 171
    2018-11-23  R35 254
    2018-11-23  R48 3054
    2018-11-30  R31 752
    2018-11-30  R32 914
    2018-11-30  R33 642
    2018-11-30  R33 905
    2018-11-30  R33 263
    2018-11-30  R34 168
    2018-11-30  R35 253
    2018-11-30  R48 2991
    2018-12-07  R31 732
    2018-12-07  R32 885
    2018-12-07  R33 627
    2018-12-07  R33 271
    2018-12-07  R33 898
    2018-12-07  R34 160
    2018-12-07  R35 238
    2018-12-07  R48 2914
    2018-12-14  R31 692
    2018-12-14  R32 841
    2018-12-14  R33 860
    2018-12-14  R33 598
    2018-12-14  R33 262
    2018-12-14  R34 153
    2018-12-14  R35 227
    2018-12-14  R48 2773
    2018-12-21  R31 676
    2018-12-21  R32 818
    2018-12-21  R33 584
    2018-12-21  R33 858
    2018-12-21  R33 274
    2018-12-21  R34 150
    2018-12-21  R35 223
    2018-12-21  R48 2725
    2018-12-28  R31 661
    2018-12-28  R32 798
    2018-12-28  R33 878
    2018-12-28  R33 582
    2018-12-28  R33 296
    2018-12-28  R34 147
    2018-12-28  R35 220
    2018-12-28  R48 2705
    2019-01-04  R31 651
    2019-01-04  R32 763
    2019-01-04  R33 865
    2019-01-04  R33 302
    2019-01-04  R33 563
    2019-01-04  R34 132
    2019-01-04  R35 204
    2019-01-04  R48 2614
    2019-01-11  R31 620
    2019-01-11  R32 729
    2019-01-11  R33 303
    2019-01-11  R33 557
    2019-01-11  R33 861
    2019-01-11  R34 127
    2019-01-11  R35 196
    2019-01-11  R48 2533
    2019-01-18  R31 566
    2019-01-18  R32 673
    2019-01-18  R33 823
    2019-01-18  R33 295
    2019-01-18  R33 528
    2019-01-18  R34 121
    2019-01-18  R35 185
    2019-01-18  R48 2370
    2019-01-25  R31 527
    2019-01-25  R32 606
    2019-01-25  R33 771
    2019-01-25  R33 493
    2019-01-25  R33 278
    2019-01-25  R34 114
    2019-01-25  R35 178
    2019-01-25  R48 2197
    2019-02-01  R31 468
    2019-02-01  R32 522
    2019-02-01  R33 451
    2019-02-01  R33 241
    2019-02-01  R33 692
    2019-02-01  R34 105
    2019-02-01  R35 172
    2019-02-01  R48 1960
    2019-02-08  R31 444
    2019-02-08  R32 492
    2019-02-08  R33 696
    2019-02-08  R33 447
    2019-02-08  R33 248
    2019-02-08  R34 95
    2019-02-08  R35 155
    2019-02-08  R48 1882
    2019-02-15  R31 395
    2019-02-15  R32 436
    2019-02-15  R33 224
    2019-02-15  R33 425
    2019-02-15  R33 649
    2019-02-15  R34 87
    2019-02-15  R35 138
    2019-02-15  R48 1705
    2019-02-22  R31 354
    2019-02-22  R32 385
    2019-02-22  R33 199
    2019-02-22  R33 399
    2019-02-22  R33 598
    2019-02-22  R34 79
    2019-02-22  R35 122
    2019-02-22  R48 1539
    2019-03-01  R31 311
    2019-03-01  R32 338
    2019-03-01  R33 377
    2019-03-01  R33 180
    2019-03-01  R33 557
    2019-03-01  R34 73
    2019-03-01  R35 112
    2019-03-01  R48 1390
    2019-03-08  R31 262
    2019-03-08  R32 287
    2019-03-08  R33 344
    2019-03-08  R33 129
    2019-03-08  R33 473
    2019-03-08  R34 66
    2019-03-08  R35 102
    2019-03-08  R48 1190
    2019-03-15  R31 245
    2019-03-15  R32 268
    2019-03-15  R33 336
    2019-03-15  R33 135
    2019-03-15  R33 471
    2019-03-15  R34 62
    2019-03-15  R35 96
    2019-03-15  R48 1143
    2019-03-22  R31 225
    2019-03-22  R32 248
    2019-03-22  R33 329
    2019-03-22  R33 137
    2019-03-22  R33 467
    2019-03-22  R34 62
    2019-03-22  R35 104
    2019-03-22  R48 1107
    2019-03-29  R31 210
    2019-03-29  R32 241
    2019-03-29  R33 347
    2019-03-29  R33 156
    2019-03-29  R33 502
    2019-03-29  R34 64
    2019-03-29  R35 113
    2019-03-29  R48 1130
    2019-04-05  R31 209
    2019-04-05  R32 240
    2019-04-05  R33 166
    2019-04-05  R33 357
    2019-04-05  R33 523
    2019-04-05  R34 64
    2019-04-05  R35 119
    2019-04-05  R48 1155
    2019-04-12  R31 228
    2019-04-12  R32 254
    2019-04-12  R33 187
    2019-04-12  R33 384
    2019-04-12  R33 571
    2019-04-12  R34 66
    2019-04-12  R35 128
    2019-04-12  R48 1247
    2019-04-19  R31 251
    2019-04-19  R32 264
    2019-04-19  R33 413
    2019-04-19  R33 616
    2019-04-19  R33 204
    2019-04-19  R34 70
    2019-04-19  R35 138
    2019-04-19  R48 1339
    2019-04-26  R31 279
    2019-04-26  R32 290
    2019-04-26  R33 442
    2019-04-26  R33 666
    2019-04-26  R33 224
    2019-04-26  R34 75
    2019-04-26  R35 152
    2019-04-26  R48 1462
    2019-05-03  R31 299
    2019-05-03  R32 309
    2019-05-03  R33 699
    2019-05-03  R33 234
    2019-05-03  R33 466
    2019-05-03  R34 78
    2019-05-03  R35 162
    2019-05-03  R48 1547
    2019-05-10  R31 330
    2019-05-10  R32 336
    2019-05-10  R33 731
    2019-05-10  R33 240
    2019-05-10  R33 491
    2019-05-10  R34 82
    2019-05-10  R35 174
    2019-05-10  R48 1653
    2019-05-17  R31 353
    2019-05-17  R32 364
    2019-05-17  R33 762
    2019-05-17  R33 249
    2019-05-17  R33 513
    2019-05-17  R34 89
    2019-05-17  R35 186
    2019-05-17  R48 1753
    2019-05-24  R31 383
    2019-05-24  R32 399
    2019-05-24  R33 793
    2019-05-24  R33 253
    2019-05-24  R33 540
    2019-05-24  R34 93
    2019-05-24  R35 198
    2019-05-24  R48 1867
    2019-05-31  R31 414
    2019-05-31  R32 436
    2019-05-31  R33 821
    2019-05-31  R33 256
    2019-05-31  R33 565
    2019-05-31  R34 101
    2019-05-31  R35 213
    2019-05-31  R48 1986
    2019-06-07  R31 440
    2019-06-07  R32 469
    2019-06-07  R33 586
    2019-06-07  R33 256
    2019-06-07  R33 842
    2019-06-07  R34 111
    2019-06-07  R35 227
    2019-06-07  R48 2088
    2019-06-14  R31 472
    2019-06-14  R32 503
    2019-06-14  R33 264
    2019-06-14  R33 875
    2019-06-14  R33 612
    2019-06-14  R34 118
    2019-06-14  R35 234
    2019-06-14  R48 2203
    2019-06-21  R31 499
    2019-06-21  R32 538
    2019-06-21  R33 630
    2019-06-21  R33 263
    2019-06-21  R33 893
    2019-06-21  R34 127
    2019-06-21  R35 245
    2019-06-21  R48 2301
    2019-06-28  R31 526
    2019-06-28  R32 568
    2019-06-28  R33 259
    2019-06-28  R33 907
    2019-06-28  R33 648
    2019-06-28  R34 134
    2019-06-28  R35 255
    2019-06-28  R48 2390
    2019-07-05  R31 544
    2019-07-05  R32 597
    2019-07-05  R33 257
    2019-07-05  R33 669
    2019-07-05  R33 927
    2019-07-05  R34 140
    2019-07-05  R35 263
    2019-07-05  R48 2471
    2019-07-12  R31 561
    2019-07-12  R32 627
    2019-07-12  R33 246
    2019-07-12  R33 683
    2019-07-12  R33 929
    2019-07-12  R34 147
    2019-07-12  R35 268
    2019-07-12  R48 2533
    2019-07-19  R31 575
    2019-07-19  R32 650
    2019-07-19  R33 921
    2019-07-19  R33 229
    2019-07-19  R33 692
    2019-07-19  R34 151
    2019-07-19  R35 271
    2019-07-19  R48 2569
    2019-07-26  R31 597
    2019-07-26  R32 677
    2019-07-26  R33 934
    2019-07-26  R33 708
    2019-07-26  R33 226
    2019-07-26  R34 156
    2019-07-26  R35 270
    2019-07-26  R48 2634
    2019-08-02  R31 613
    2019-08-02  R32 701
    2019-08-02  R33 941
    2019-08-02  R33 719
    2019-08-02  R33 221
    2019-08-02  R34 161
    2019-08-02  R35 272
    2019-08-02  R48 2689
    2019-08-09  R31 634
    2019-08-09  R32 729
    2019-08-09  R33 939
    2019-08-09  R33 725
    2022-12-30  R32 839
    2022-12-30  R33 770
    2022-12-30  R33 270
    2022-12-30  R33 1040
    2022-12-30  R34 157
    2022-12-30  R35 165
    2022-12-30  R48 2891
    2023-01-06  R31 700
    2023-01-06  R32 823
    2023-01-06  R33 1067
    2023-01-06  R33 772
    2023-01-06  R33 295
    2023-01-06  R34 153
    2023-01-06  R35 160
    2023-01-06  R48 2902
    2023-01-13  R31 662
    2023-01-13  R32 785
    2023-01-13  R33 762
    2023-01-13  R33 1069
    2023-01-13  R33 307
    2023-01-13  R34 147
    2023-01-13  R35 157
    2023-01-13  R48 2820
    2023-01-20  R31 622
    2023-01-20  R32 754
    2023-01-20  R33 310
    2023-03-24  R31 343
    2023-03-24  R32 437
    2023-05-05  R31 422
    2023-05-05  R32 497
    2023-05-05  R33 1002
    2023-05-05  R33 287
    2023-05-05  R33 715
    2023-05-05  R34 104
    2023-05-05  R35 114
    2023-05-05  R48 2141
    2023-05-12  R31 458
    2023-05-12  R32 520
    2023-05-12  R33 1023
    2023-05-12  R33 290
    2023-05-12  R33 734
    2023-05-12  R34 112
    2023-05-12  R35 127
    2023-05-12  R48 2240
```

I'd like to calculate a trailing 5 year average of values grouped on 'series' and for each period date (ie, an average will be calculated for each series/period record).

For a given period and series record, the values used in the average calculation should represent each of the last five years previous values with its dayofyear being closes to that of the anchor record.

As a simple case, for series R48, date 5/12/2023, the trailing 5y average returned should be 1889 using the sample data below:

```
period  series  value
2018-05-04  R48 1432
2018-05-11  R48 1538
2018-05-18  R48 1629
2018-05-25  R48 1725
2019-05-03  R48 1547
2019-05-10  R48 1653
2019-05-17  R48 1753
2019-05-24  R48 1867
2019-05-31  R48 1986
2020-05-01  R48 2319
2020-05-08  R48 2422
2020-05-15  R48 2503
2020-05-22  R48 2612
2020-05-29  R48 2714
2021-05-07  R48 2029
2021-05-14  R48 2100
2021-05-21  R48 2215
2021-05-28  R48 2313
2022-05-06  R48 1643
2022-05-13  R48 1732
2022-05-20  R48 1819
2022-05-27  R48 1901
2023-05-05  R48 2141
2023-05-12  R48 2240
```

For the time being, this code works (ignoring complications for dates with less than 5y of data, etc).  Would prefer a more direct approach to solving this though.  Appreciate all input.

```
for s in df.series.unique():
    a = df[(df.series==s)]

    for i in a[df.period.dt.year >= 2013].period:
        d = a[(a.period > (i - pd.DateOffset(months=61))) & (a.period.dt.year < i.year)]
        d['d'] = abs(a.period.dt.dayofyear - int(i.strftime('%j')))
        df.loc[(df.period==i) & (df.series==s),'5yavg'] = d.loc[d.groupby(d.period.dt.year).d.idxmin()].value.mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code groups by "series", then calculates rolling trailing 5-year mean.  Slightly more code than your own, however.  I arrive at a slightly different value for `2023-05-12`, as I have found nearest based on date rather than day of year, which causes a difference in 2020 which has an extra day in February so all days after Feb. in 2020 will be greater by 1 day (so 08-05-2020 is closer than 15-05-2020 for 12-05-2023).  If this is what you would prefer, it is easy to change the code.

```py
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r'\s{1,}', engine="python")
df["period"] = pd.to_datetime(df["period"])

# create list for grouping series
series_list = []

# loop through each series
for i, j in df.groupby("series"):
    # create 2 columns for dates, without year and year only
    j["no_year"] = pd.to_datetime(
        j.period.dt.strftime("%d-%m"), format="%d-%m")
    j["year"] = j.period.dt.year

    # set years as columns
    k = j.set_index(["no_year", "year"]).value.unstack()
    if len(j) > 2:
        # fill na values with nearest date value
        k = k.interpolate(method="nearest").ffill().bfill()
    else:
        # can't interpolate if <= 2 rows
        k = k.ffill().bfill()

    # calculate rolling mean of 5 years (not including current year)
    l = k.T.rolling(5, min_periods=1, closed="left").mean().T.stack()
    l.name = "mean"
    # merge means to j
    m = pd.merge(j, l, left_on=["no_year", "year"], right_index=True, how="left")
    m = m[list(df.columns) + ["mean"]]
    
    series_list += [m]

# concatenate series groups to one dataframe
df1 = pd.concat(series_list).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
df1
# Out[]: 
#        period series  value         mean
# 0  2018-05-04    R48   1432          NaN
# 1  2018-05-11    R48   1538          NaN
# 2  2018-05-18    R48   1629          NaN
# 3  2018-05-25    R48   1725          NaN
# 4  2019-05-03    R48   1547  1432.000000
# 5  2019-05-10    R48   1653  1538.000000
# 6  2019-05-17    R48   1753  1629.000000
# 7  2019-05-24    R48   1867  1725.000000
# 8  2019-05-31    R48   1986  1725.000000
# 9  2020-05-01    R48   2319  1489.500000
# 10 2020-05-08    R48   2422  1595.500000
# 11 2020-05-15    R48   2503  1691.000000
# 12 2020-05-22    R48   2612  1796.000000
# 13 2020-05-29    R48   2714  1855.500000
# 14 2021-05-07    R48   2029  1835.666667
# 15 2021-05-14    R48   2100  1931.333333
# 16 2021-05-21    R48   2215  2036.000000
# 17 2021-05-28    R48   2313  2141.666667
# 18 2022-05-06    R48   1643  1857.500000
# 19 2022-05-13    R48   1732  1948.500000
# 20 2022-05-20    R48   1819  2052.250000
# 21 2022-05-27    R48   1901  2154.750000
# 22 2023-05-05    R48   2141  1814.600000
# 23 2023-05-12    R48   2240  1905.200000
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Will prob take a closer look and pull pieces of it